# Beginners: Navigation/Interface question

Tags: modeling, transforms, axis

I am sorry if this is a dumb question. I am new to blender.

I am following a demo. At some point something changed and now I have an object and the interface also shows a small xyz axis diagram on the Modeling window. It was ok for me but now When I try to move or rotate an object, the xyz axis rotates or moves instead of the object. no matter which of the 2 objects I have, any action affects only the axis but the object remains. I am using global Orientation, and Median point. I tried changing both setting with same result. My steps are: In object mode, select the object, it shows as highlighted, Click R to rotate, I start to move the mouse to rotate it and then the slected oject is no longer selected but the Axis rotates. Same when using "G": to move it. The axis move but not the object.

I am not sure how to disable this axis. See the following snapshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled the *Affect Only Origins* option, it allows you to transform the object origin but you can't move anything else unless you deactivate this option:

[image]